# Sklearn inverse_transform return only one column when fit to many

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to inverse_transform one column with sklearn, when the initial transformer was fit on the whole data set? Below is an example of what I am trying to get after.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Setting up a dummy pipeline
pipes = []
pipes.append(('scaler', MinMaxScaler()))
transformation_pipeline = Pipeline(pipes)

# Random data.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'data1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     'data2': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'Y': [1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2]
    }
)

# Fitting the transformation pipeline
test = transformation_pipeline.fit_transform(df)

# Pulling the scaler function from the pipeline.
scaler = transformation_pipeline.named_steps['scaler']

# This is what I thought may work.
predicted_transformed = scaler.inverse_transform(test['Y'])

# The output would look something like this
# Essentially overlooking that scaler was fit on 3 variables and fitting
# the last one, or any I need.
predicted_transfromed = [1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

I need to be able to fit the whole dataset as part of a data prep process. But then I am importing the scaler later into another instance with sklearn.externals joblibs. In this new instance the predicted values are the only thing that exists. So I need to extract just the inverse scaler for the Y column to get back the originals.

I am aware that I could fit one transformer for X variables and Y variables, However, I would like to avoid this. This method would add to the complexity of moving the scalers around and maintaining both of them in future projects.

Comment: Then you can use the appropriate value from `scale_` and `min_` attributes of the scaler object.

Comment: @VivekKumar could you show an example of what you mean in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late but I think this code does what you are looking for:

```
# - scaler   = the scaler object (it needs an inverse_transform method)
# - data     = the data to be inverse transformed as a Series, ndarray, ... 
#              (a 1d object you can assign to a df column)
# - ftName   = the name of the column to which the data belongs
# - colNames = all column names of the data on which scaler was fit 
#              (necessary because scaler will only accept a df of the same shape as the one it was fit on)
def invTransform(scaler, data, colName, colNames):
    dummy = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(data), len(colNames))), columns=colNames)
    dummy[colName] = data
    dummy = pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(dummy), columns=colNames)
    return dummy[colName].values
```

Note that you need to provide enough information to run use the `inverse_transform` method of the `scaler` object behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems.  I have a multidimensional timeseries as input (a quantity and 'exogenous' variables), and one dimension (a quantity) as output. I am unable to invert the scaling to compare the forecast to the original test set, since the scaler expects a multidimensional input.

One solution I can think of is **using separate scalers for the quantity and the exogenous columns**.

Another solution I can think of is to **give the scaler sufficient 'junk' columns just to fill out the dimensions of the array to be unscaled**, then only look at the first column of the output.

Then, once I forecast, I can invert the scaling on the forecast to get values which I can compare to the test set.

Answer (score -1):

Improving on what Willem said. This will work with less input.

```
def invTransform(scaler, data):
    dummy = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(data), scaler.n_features_in_)))
    dummy[0] = data
    dummy = pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(dummy), columns=dummy.columns)
    return dummy[0].values
```

Comment: This is totally wrong. You are placing the data on the first column every time so there is a good chance that you are scaling with the wrong scaler if your original data was not on the first column.