# How to make inverse_transform over a different df shape than the one where the fit was applied?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, inverse-transform

I have the next DF and I use standardscaler.

```
#datos
               LIBRANZA IPC IBR
FECHA           
2020-10-09  2.000   5.620   1.741
2020-10-10  0.000   5.620   1.741
2020-10-11  0.000   5.620   1.741
2020-10-12  0.000   5.620   1.741
2020-10-13  1.000   5.620   1.744
```

I have like result the next DF.

```
#datos_estandarizados
           LIBRANZA IPC IBR
FECHA           
2020-10-09  -1.281  -0.393  -0.871
2020-10-10  -1.298  -0.393  -0.871
2020-10-11  -1.298  -0.393  -0.871
2020-10-12  -1.298  -0.393  -0.871
2020-10-13  -1.290  -0.393  -0.871
```

With the last DF I'm running different ML models to get a forecast over the variable LIBRANZA which is the objective, but I have a problem when I'm trying to get inverse_transform over the forecast because the fit was made over a different shape of the DF I think, but not sure. I'm getting the next error, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (932,1) doesn't match the 
broadcast shape (932,3)
```

Some who can help me to solve it pls.

These is the Code to fit

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

encabezados = datos.columns
index = datos.index

scaler = StandardScaler()

X_estandarizado = scaler.fit_transform(datos)

datos_estandarizados = pd.DataFrame(X_estandarizado, index=index, columns=encabezados)

#Completa los huecos en la serie con NULL
datos_estandarizados = datos_estandarizados.asfreq('D') 

datos_estandarizados.head()
```

and this is the code to inverse_transform

```
prediccion_libranza = predicciones2.reset_index(drop=False)

prediccion_libranza.columns = ["FECHA", "PREDICCIÓN"]

prediccion_libranza = prediccion_libranza.set_index('FECHA')

X_desestandarizado = scaler.inverse_transform(prediccion_libranza)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sklearn inverse\_transform return only one column when fit to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049396/sklearn-inverse-transform-return-only-one-column-when-fit-to-many)